# What is the easiest approach to get freeRDP installed onto Amazon Linux?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

What is the easiest approach to get freeRDP installed onto Amazon Linux?

I've tried using RPMForge but am not having luck.  Getting errors that dependencies like `libpulse.so.0` are missing.

Would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below steps to compile freeRDP

```
  git clone git://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP.git
  cd FreeRDP
```

Build:

```
  make
```

Install:

```
  sudo make install
```

Now create /etc/ld.so.conf.d/freerdp.conf and add the following line to it:

```
  /usr/local/lib/freerdp
```

For a 64-bit rhel based OS add:
     /usr/local/lib64/freerdp

Depending on your OS/distribution, you may also need to add this line:

```
 /usr/local/lib
```

Run ldconfig. You should now have xfreerdp installed in /usr/local/bin:

```
  which xfreerdp
 /usr/local/bin/xfreerdp
```

Plugins are installed in /usr/local/lib/freerdp:

```
 /usr/local/lib/freerdp$ ls
```

cliprdr.so  disk.so  drdynvc.so  printer.so  rail.so  rdpdbg.so  rdpdr.so  rdpsnd_alsa.so  rdpsnd.so
keymaps are installed in /usr/local/share/freerdp:

```
  /usr/local/share/freerdp$ ls keymaps/
```

aliases  ataritt       empty  fujitsu  ibm        macosx    sony  xfree86  xkb.pl
amiga    digital_vndr  evdev  hp       macintosh  sgi_vndr  sun   xfree98
After launching FreeRDP at least once, ~/.freerdp will be created to store known hosts:

```
  ~/.freerdp$ ls
```

cacert  known_hosts